# Ubuntu not detecting battery on HP x2 210 G2

Tags: linux, windows, laptop, battery, acpi

I've installed Ubuntu on this laptop (three flavours) after wiping the system of the original copy of Windows that it came with, and while it was mostly functional, one major aspect that concerned me wasn't: I could not get the system to recognize the battery at all. Using `acpi -b` returns blank. I tried reinstalling Windows (an evaluation copy) on it but I couldn't find the appropriate Windows drivers on the HP website for it - I could have waited for the update to complete though, but I'm not sure if that would solve the issue.

Are there any solutions for this? I don't know where to start. I've once been told to use [this](https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/guide-patching-laptop-dsdt-ssdts.152573/), but this appears to be beyond my current capabilities. I am aware that there's been a bug about battery detection that some Linux devices have and that the firmware on this device may be difficult to work with.

Comment: First of all look for and install the latest BIOS/UEFI version published by HP.

Comment: I'm having trouble updating the BIOS, but I'll try dual-booting instead as is for now